# Why does Python tell me **TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'** when I have a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have the following dataframe and a similar second one which I want to compare.
The problem is that I think I confuse datatypes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv("csv", delimiter=';', header=None, skiprows=1, names=['1', '2']))
df['1'].str.replace(r'[^\w\s]+', '')
df['1'] = df1['1'].str.replace('\d+', '')
df = df.apply(nltk.word_tokenize)
df = [nltk.word_tokenize(str(1)) for 1in df]
df = df.apply(lambda x: [item.lower() for item in x if item.lower() not in stop_words])
df = set(df)
```

**TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'**

Answer (score 1):

On your second to last line you are generating a Series of lists. Then you are converting that series to a set. You can't do that, because the elements of a set need to be hashable, and lists are not (as it says in the TypeError). In contrast to lists, tuples are hashable. Assuming that the rest of your code works (I have no way of checking), try

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: tuple(item.lower() for item in x if item.lower() not in stop_words))
df = set(df)
```

Comment: Now it says **AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'apply'** on your first line of code

Comment: I also tried it without the apply and lower() is not possible with lists either. So the list seems to exist before that second last line even though it must be a dataframe

Comment: The problem seems to be in the first line after the dataframe because a datafram does not have strings

Comment: It's hard to tell without a a complete example. For example, `[nltk.word_tokenize(str(1)) for 1in df]` is also not valid python.

Comment: the 1 is there instead of the row name. I want to compare ["Paul eats an apple"] in df1 with ["Eva eats a pineapple"] in df2 and this with 500 rows in df1 and 6000 in df2. For this I need to tokenize them and turn them into sets

Comment: Meaning it worked when I used only one dataframe and one row